# MS AJAX add_init and Sys.loadScripts

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Has anyone tried using the new AJAX script loader to load Sys.Component dependencies?

For example, I have an IScriptControl, which gets instantiated during page load with $create, but the component has a dependency on another file, which is loaded asynchronously with Sys.loadScripts().

Blah.js:

```
Type.registerNamespace('Blah');
```

MyComponent.js:

```
Sys.loadScripts(['blah.js'], function() {
    Blah.MyComponent = function() {
        Blah.MyComponent.initializeBase(this);
    };
    Blah.MyComponent.prototype = {
        // ...
    };

Blah.MyComponent.registerClass('Blah.MyComponent', Sys.Component);
});
```

MyPage.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyComponent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Blah.MyComponent, ...);
    // This fails, because it runs before MyComponent has been initialized, which in turn is waiting for blah.js to load
});
</script>
```

It seems that the `Sys.Application.init` event doesn't wait for any sync scripts to finish loading, and `Sys.loadScripts` doesn't block, so the initialization fails.

I could hack the add_init function to load the component script asynchronously, e.g.:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    // load component asynchronously
    Sys.loadScripts(['MyComponent.js'], function() {
        $create(...);
    });
});
```

This would probably work, but it just feels wrong. Instead of just calling `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptControl`, I'd have to roll my own initialization code. What's the right way to handle this scenario?

Thanks!